# SqlConnectionStringBuilder ConnectTimeout не работает

Tags: c#, sql

Мне необходимо установить время ожидания соединения не более 3 х секунд. Но все равно попытка соеденения идет 15 или более секунд. Вот код:

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection = null;
object resultObj = null;
try
{
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    builder.ConnectTimeout = 3;
    builder.DataSource = serverName;
    builder.InitialCatalog = dbName;
    builder.IntegratedSecurity = false;
    builder.Password = password;
    builder.UserID = login;
    using (sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, sqlConnection))
        {
            resultObj = sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }

    sqlConnection.Close();
}
```

Коннекшн стринг формируется правильно и с таймаутом 3 секунды. Но это не дает никакого эффекта. Все равно ожидание 15 сек по факту.

В чем может быть проблема ?

Comment: Любопытный вопрос. Возможно, проблема в том что вы ставите `connection.ConnectTimeout`, но не ставите `command.CommandTimeout`. [Тынц](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10108565/5752652) Рекомендую почитать целиком ответы, например и тот где жалуются на `absolutely insane design decision`.

Comment: @AKК сожалению ничего по ссылке не помогло. Да и соединение устнавливается до начала отправки команды. Я вообще убрал код команды а просто попытался установить соединение , то все равно не реагирует на тайаут.

Comment: Так, на всякий случай по пулу коннектов уточню: в этом приложении только этот один код, никто не пытается переиспользовать этот коннект? И вот ещё подумал: а каким способом проверяете время и чем замеряете результат?

Comment: Всё правильно работает. Используете CommandTimeout - она задаёт лимит на выполнение команды, а не СonnectTimeout

Comment: @nick_n_a мне выполнение команды второстепенно, необходимо для начала проверить коннект. Команду можно вообще не трогать

Comment: Так коннект = Socket ответ получил, но ответ коннекта, это не результат выполнения команды.

Comment: Используется LocalDB или полноценный Sql Server?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Полноценный сервер

Comment: Вам не нужно вызывать явно `sqlConnection.Close()`, так как выше у вас `using`, который делает это за вас.

Comment: На удивление, ничего толкового не гуглится. Судя по [этой](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d8c87fb8-2ef2-429f-af52-20e9e0074357/changing-default-connection-timeout-value-for-sql-connection?forum=csharpgeneral) теме (см. сообщение cesardgo почти в конце) этот таймаут зависит от того, жив или нет сам Сервер, или, вернее, кто даёт отклик: сама СУБД или её окружение (хост).

Comment: Я почему и спрашивал про LocalDB: эта СУБД стартует при запуске приложения (и отключается при его завершении) и нужно время на инициализацию.